# Why is aluminium foil wrapped around a Leyden jar?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

In the process of constructing a water Leyden jar, a foil of aluminium had to wrapped around the outside of the Leyden jar. What purpose does it fulfill?

Answer (score 1):

The Leyden jar is a rudimentary capacitor. The foil on the outside is one of the electrodes ("plates") of the capacitor, the bottle is the insulator. Charge is stored on the inside of the foil (where it is being attracted by the equal-but-opposite charge on the foil on the inside of the bottle).

Comment: When a charged object is placed on the metal conductor sticking outside of the jar, the electricity flows from the nail to the foil inside, while the foil outside is properly insulated  from the nail. Where does the outside foil get its charge from?

Comment: The outside foil gets its charge from the charged object you touch it with. This charge then pulls the opposite charge to the inside foil.

Comment: But there is an insulator in the way. How can charge pass through that one?

Comment: Charge does not pass through the insulator - the electric field "pulls" charge to the plate on the other side (and that plate in turn "borrows" the charge from whatever else is attached, e.g. The mail in the cap...)